# How to uncheck disabled checkedlistbox in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

[image]

In the above image "ug(User Group)" is a row in a checkedlistbox with enabled property to false. How to uncheck "ug(User Group)" in disabled state.

Comment: You need to uncheck it Pragmatically? your requirement is not clear enough

Comment: use chkListBox.SetItemChecked(1, false);

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use

```
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(2, false);
```

or

```
checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(2, CheckState.Unhecked);
```

The `Enabled` property of the `CheckedListBox` has no impact on the check state of the items or those two methods.

---

MSDN links:

- [CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [CheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemcheckstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

*UPDATE:* Disabling a single item in the `CheckedListBox` instead of disabling the whole control is not possible out of the box.

If you want to prevent the user from changing the check state of one special item, you need to subscribe to the `ItemCheck` event of the `CheckedListBox`:

```
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Index == 2)
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
}
```

This event is fired *before* the check state of the item changed. `e` is an `ItemCheckEventArgs` that contains the item's `Index`, its current check state (`CurrentValue`) and the check state it shall have afterwards (`NewValue`).

So setting `e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked` prevents the item from being checked again by the user.

Comment: i need checkbox with readonly and unchecked, Chekedlistbox.SetItemCheckState(2, CheckState.Indeterminate);  but i need to remove check from checkbox

Comment: @rahuls Don't understand your problem. It's exactly what the code shown does. Use `CheckState.Unchecked` instead of `Indeterminate`.

Comment: CheckState.Unchecked is correct but i need to make as readonly .User can't able to check.

Comment: @rahuls updated my answer to show how to prevent checking the item.